# c# Passing an index of a list item from one form to another

Tags: c#, winforms

In c#, how do you write the code so that when a user select an item in list box and click edit, it's data displays in separate textboxes in another windows form? I'm guessing the passing of the selected index between the two forms is required.

Comment: ..this question (similar, anyway) has been asked at least 300 times this week. I'd suggest searching.

Comment: Passing "an index" requires both forms to have access to the same list. This can cause threading and synchronization problems. Consider passing a copy of the selected data to the other form.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a Form and set a String property. Every time you click edit button, just pass that item's text to the Form's contructor.